# Distribution Fitting: does every continuous distribution have a discrete distribution equivalent?

Tags: distributions

Sometimes you find a good fit in a continuous distribution function, but the data is discrete.

Normal and Binomial are automatic pairs. Both symmetrical, non-skewed.

Does this exist for others?

Comment: Data are always discrete. It’s fine to call your $x_1,...,x_n$ as being normally distributed, since you’re saying that they come from a population that has a normal distribution.

Comment: I would not say binomial is automatically a pair for the normal: (i) the binomial is typically asymmetric (the only exception being $p=\frac12$), while the normal is never asymmetric; (ii) the binomial is limited to values between 0 and n while the normal is not bounded. (iii) in the binomial the variance is a function of the mean parameter (if p is large or small, the variance is small), not so for the normal. If I wanted a continuous distribution that behaved "like" the binomial I wouldn't pick the normal.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Oh okay. For the symmetry part, according to this source (https://www.statsdirect.com/help/distributions/binomial.htm), `The shape of a binomial distribution is symmetrical when p=0.5 or when n is large.` So in a large data set, it should be symmetrical regardless of p?

Comment: @Dave What do you mean by data is always discrete? What about population vs height?

Comment: No. (i) In that quote, "n" doesn't represent the number of observations in the sample; it's a parameter in the distribution. (How could sampling more of the population change the shape of the population??). Imagine I conduct an experiment where I toss a (potentially) biased coin 10 times and count the number of heads. If I conduct the experiment 40 times I have a sample size of 40, but the n-parameter is 10. (ii) the statement is not strictly correct; if p is not 0.5 it's asymmetric, but as n grows the asymmetry becomes smaller (e.g. the skewness is proportional to $1/√n$)

Comment: @NoName What do you mean by population vs height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is obviously "yes", because you can discretize every continuous distribution by splitting the real axis into cells $I_k=[x_{min}+(k-1)\Delta x,x+k\cdot\Delta x)$ and then define
\begin{equation}P(k) := P(X\in I_k) = \int_{I_k} f(x)\,dx\end{equation}
Alternatively, you could compute the CDF at only discrete points:
$$F(x)=P(X\leq k) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_{min}\,+k\Delta x}f(x)\,dx$$
It is not guaranteed, however, that the resulting discrete distribution occurs so frequent in nature that someone took the trouble of giving it a name. For the normal distribution and the binomial distribution (with $p=0.5$), the above equations only hold approximately, but for the *exponential* and the *geometric distribution*, they hold exactly:
$$\sum_{k=1}^t p\cdot q^{k-1} = 1-q^t = \int_0^t \lambda\,e^{-\lambda s}ds \quad\mbox{with}\quad q=e^{-\lambda}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is flawed.  While you might be able to set up a situation in which a normal distribution is fit to binomial data, the choice is not yours to make, but rather dictated by the form of the data and the phenomenon generating it.  Binomial data is discrete, and if generated by the binomial distribution, it should not be fit by a continuous distribution like the Gaussian.  You can find many cases of distributions that appear visually similar, at least in some parameter spaces, but that does not mean one is applicable to the other.